# how to union this query

Tags: t-sql

```
WITH LatestJob AS (SELECT * FROM(SELECT  
   aId 
   , Position 
   , StartDate 
   ,  Enddate 
   ,SpecializationId
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aId ORDER BY  
             CASE WHEN Enddate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,  
             (CAST(Enddate as datetime)) DESC) AS RN 
FROM EmploymentDetails ed) E WHERE RN=1 
)
                      ,EarliestStart AS (SELECT aID
                                                , sum(DATEDIFF(YEAR,Startdate, isnull(Enddate,getdate()))) AS YearsExperience 
                                         FROM EmploymentDetails GROUP BY aId)
                      SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
                      , lj.Position AS LatestPosition
                      ,aps.cId,aps.ApStatusID as ApplicationStatus,aps.sId as SpecializationId
                      ,  YearsExperience
                      , ad.ExpectedSalary, REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
                      FROM Users u JOIN LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
                  JOIN EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
                  JOIN ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
                  JOIN ApplicationStatus aps ON aps.aId=u.Id    


WITH LatestJob AS (SELECT * FROM(SELECT  
   aId 
   , Position 
   , StartDate 
   ,  Enddate 
   ,SpecializationId    
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aId ORDER BY  
             CASE WHEN Enddate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,  
             (CAST(Enddate as datetime)) DESC) AS RN 
FROM EmploymentDetails ed) E WHERE RN=1 
)
                      ,EarliestStart AS (SELECT aID
                                                , sum(DATEDIFF(YEAR,Startdate, isnull(Enddate,getdate()))) AS YearsExperience 
                                         FROM EmploymentDetails GROUP BY aId)
                      SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
                      , lj.Position AS LatestPosition
                      ,  YearsExperience
                      , ad.ExpectedSalary, REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
                      FROM Users u JOIN LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
                  JOIN EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
                  JOIN ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
                    where u.RoleId=3 
                    and u.UserStatusId=1
                    and lj.SpecializationId=38 --@sId
```

Comment: Have you tried writing UNION between the two queries?

Comment: yes , i tried it but i got an errors

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might do it (I also made it a little more readable):

```
    WITH LatestJob AS (
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT  
            aId 
           ,Position 
           ,StartDate 
           ,Enddate 
           ,SpecializationId
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aId ORDER BY 
                 (CASE WHEN Enddate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC
                ,CAST(Enddate AS datetime) DESC
            ) AS RN 
        FROM 
            EmploymentDetails ed
        ) E 
    WHERE RN = 1 
    )
    ,EarliestStart AS (
        SELECT 
             aID
            ,SUM(DATEDIFF(YEAR, Startdate, ISNULL(Enddate,GETDATE()))) AS YearsExperience 
        FROM 
            EmploymentDetails 
        GROUP BY 
            aId
    )
    (
    SELECT
         u.Id
        ,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
        ,lj.Position AS LatestPosition
        ,aps.cId
        ,aps.ApStatusID AS ApplicationStatus
        ,aps.sId AS SpecializationId
        ,YearsExperience
        ,ad.ExpectedSalary
        ,REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
    FROM 
        Users u 
    JOIN 
        LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
    JOIN 
        EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
    JOIN 
        ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
    JOIN 
        ApplicationStatus aps ON aps.aId=u.Id    
    )
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT 
         u.Id
        ,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
        ,lj.Position AS LatestPosition
        ,YearsExperience
        ,ad.ExpectedSalary
        ,REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
    FROM 
        Users u 
    JOIN 
        LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
    JOIN 
        EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
    JOIN 
        ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
    WHERE 
        u.RoleId = 3 
        AND u.UserStatusId = 1
        AND lj.SpecializationId = 38 --@sId
)
```

Hopefully I didn't lose any information or copy it down wrong along the way. It only parses correctly so I'm not sure if it will actually return what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WITH LatestJob AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  
           aId 
           , Position 
           , StartDate 
           ,  Enddate 
           ,SpecializationId
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aId ORDER BY  
                     CASE WHEN Enddate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,  
                     (CAST(Enddate as datetime)) DESC) AS RN 
        FROM EmploymentDetails ed) E WHERE RN=1 
    )
), EarliestStart AS (
    SELECT aID, sum(DATEDIFF(YEAR,Startdate, isnull(Enddate,getdate()))) AS YearsExperience 
    FROM EmploymentDetails GROUP BY aId
)

  SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
      , lj.Position AS LatestPosition
      ,aps.cId,aps.ApStatusID as ApplicationStatus,aps.sId as SpecializationId
      ,  YearsExperience
      , ad.ExpectedSalary, REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
  FROM Users u 
  JOIN LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
  JOIN EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
  JOIN ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
  JOIN ApplicationStatus aps ON aps.aId=u.Id    

  UNION ALL

  SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS NAME
      , lj.Position AS LatestPosition
      , '' as cId, '' as ApplicationStatus, '' as SpecializationId
      ,  YearsExperience
      , ad.ExpectedSalary, REPLACE(ISNULL(Address1, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(Address2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(City, ''), ', ,', ',') AS Address
  FROM Users u 
  JOIN LatestJob lj ON u.Id = lj.aid 
  JOIN EarliestStart ye ON ye.aId = u.Id 
  JOIN ApplicantDetails ad ON ad.aId = u.Id
  WHERE u.RoleId=3 
    AND u.UserStatusId=1
    AND lj.SpecializationId=38 --@sId
```